# Does tmux have a mouse mode variable?

Tags: tmux

As per the tmux [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html), `tmux` contains many variables (e.g. `window_zoomed_flag`) that can be conditionally displayed in the status bar (e.g. `#{window_zoomed_flag,ON,OFF}`).

I am looking for a variable / flag that would indicate whether the mouse mode is ON or OFF (i.e. controlled by `set -g mouse on` / `set -g mouse off`), with the intent of displaying it in the status bar, similarly to that `window_zoomed_flag`.

There are some variables related to mouse in tmux 2.8:

```
 mouse_all_flag                  Pane mouse all flag
 mouse_any_flag                  Pane mouse any flag
 mouse_button_flag               Pane mouse button flag
 mouse_line                      Line under mouse, if any
 mouse_sgr_flag                  Pane mouse SGR flag
 mouse_standard_flag             Pane mouse standard flag
 mouse_utf8_flag                 Pane mouse UTF-8 flag
 mouse_word                      Word under mouse, if any
 mouse_x                         Mouse X position, if any
 mouse_y                         Mouse Y position, if any
```

However none of them seem to indicate whether mouse mode is ON. **Am I missing something? Is there a way to detect whether mouse mode is on, other than using variables?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The manual](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#FORMATS) states [emphasis mine]:

> Format variables are enclosed in `#{` and `}`, for example `#{session_name}`. The possible variables are listed […], **or the name of a tmux option may be used for an option's value**.

Try `#{mouse}` or `#{mouse,ON,OFF}`.

It will show the effective value, i.e. the non-global option if set to any value, otherwise the global option.